# How can I make a function work when I open my program? Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have made a function in python and I want to run that function when I open my program, I don't want to press any thing to make the function run.
I have tried a lot of things but unfortunately I haven't found a way to make it work on startup.
It looks something like this:

```
def check_settings():
    if view_setting == "1":
        view_menu.entryconfig("Change Background", state = "normal")
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running the script directly and not importing it as a module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_settings()
```

Comment: The issue wasn't really there but thanks it still helped.

Answer (score 0):

simply call the function

```
def check_settings():
    if view_setting == "1":
        view_menu.entryconfig("Change Background", state = "normal")

check_settings()
```